# Permission denied error while importing a table into HDFS using Scoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop, cloudera, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I am new to Hadoop. I have connected to Cloudera quickstart VM. I am trying to import the categories table present in MySQL retail_db in HDFS but I am getting permission denied error. Following is the code.

```
sqoop import \
--connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" \
--username root \
--password cloudera \
--table categories \
--target-dir /queryresult20
```

Error message -

org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): Permission denied: user=cloudera, access=WRITE, inode="/":hdfs:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x

Comment: As error says, only user `hdfs` has privilege to WRITE to the root "/" directory. Create a new directory (in /users/cloudera for example) and change --target-dir to be that.

Comment: @mazaneicha - Thank you. Why the error message is saying Permission denied for user Cloudera though my sqoop command is using root user?

Comment: Not really- root maybe used to connect to/read from mysql, but a write to hadoop will be done either by user defined via env. var `HADOOP_USERNAME` (in unsecure environment) or by a Kerberos-authenticated user (in secure case) whose ticket is cached in krb5cc file.